# Comparing cells but skipping the ones with zero in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I have 7 variables which can in principle be between 0 and 10. (Up to) 2 of those are usually 0 and therefore "not interesting" and I would like to skip them when checking if the variables are the same. So, put differently, I would like to check if the non-zero values are the same.

An example, I have these 7 variable: 1 0 1 0 1 1 1, so the non-zero are all 1 and therefore the same.

Second example: 1 0 2 1 0 1 1, the non-zero variables are not the same, therefore False.

I thought I could reduce my 7 variable to just the 5 non-zero ones and then check if they are the same by using
`=IF(AND(b1=b2,b2=b3,b3=b4,b4=b5),1,0)`
But I am not sure how to get from the 7 to the 5 variables, even if I know the position of the zero values.

Here what I tried in Excel:

[image]

Columns A-G are the 7 variables, the input,
in column G and H I figure out where the 0s are located with the idea to skip them BUT
I cannot figure out how to get to b1-b5, I had to do it manually in the example.

Any ideas? Maybe an array formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula has no limitations on the max or minimum number of `0` instances.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:G1,">0")*MAX(A1:G1)=SUM(A1:G1)
```

If anyone needed a non-numeric solution, try something like this:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,A1:G1),"0",""),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,A1:G1),"0",""),1),""))=0
```

[image]

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried to save some face and come up with something slightly different than yours. It's a stretch, but thanks for the original correction.

Comment: Options are good.  As you probably saw I kept refining my second option.

Comment: Yeah it's fun to tinker and optimize answer. I think your `maxifs` seems the cleanest, but of course has the Excel Version limits. I was going to try to tackle making it a dynamic spill range, but I have to get some other stuff done...

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS to determine if 5 of the product of the sum divided by 5 appear in the range:

```
=--(COUNTIFS(A11:G11,SUM(A11:G11)/5)=5)
```

[image]

Of course if one has MINIFS:

```
=--(MAX(A11:G11)=MINIFS(A11:G11,A11:G11,">0")))
```

[image]

Comment: =--(COUNTIFS(A11:G11,SUM(A11:G11)/5)=5) is my favorite answer as it does not need a new version of Excel and it also was the easiest to understand for me. I have even modified it to COUNTIF() as opposed to COUNTIFS() to make it even more compatible with older versions of Excel.

Am I correct that "--" stands for *(-1)*(-1) and this converts the TRUE/FALSE result into 1/0 which is of course much more elegant than my crude IF(..., 1, 0).

Comment: @Gecko in the interest of a friendly debate, my answer `=COUNTIF(A1:G1,">0")...` is the most compatible as it works in Excel 2010 vs. `Countifs` requires 2013. Additionally, Scott's formula will only work if there are exactly two `0` while you said you could have *UP TO 2* `0`.  So if you had less than 2 values of `0` the result would be incorrect, while mine has no `0` limitation. Final friendly jab... you have to see the irony of declaring this answer easiest to understand then ask what's it doing =)  Your assumption is correct (0/1). No worries on picking Scott's. Fun question.

Comment: @pgSystemTester You are right, "up to 2" is correctly handled by your formula, I have changed my pick.
Scott's version of COUNTIF without the "S" and your COUNTIF version are both compatible even with Excel 2003 which I occasionally use because it launches the fastest.

Comment: Thanks for playing along and for being a good sport about my jabs (I wasn't expecting a switched answer!). 

Curious... according to MS Website Countif only works starting in 2010. I'd be curious how it functions in 2003?? Also curious why you believe 2003 performs faster?

Comment: @pgSystemTester if you are talking to me, The points do not matter.  As you probably noticed I answer a lot of questions in the comments.  I only care that the op gets something that works for them.

Comment: @pgSystemTester I have tested Countif with Excel 2003, works very well. Happy to share the workbook but not much in there except for your, Scott's and Tom's formulas. With regards to the performance of 2003, I was referring to the launch of the program (Windows) on my old PC, 2003 takes 0.3s to open, 2010 1.1s and 2019 takes 1.6s (always with the Analysis ToolPak add-in). So if I want to add two numbers then I will use Excel 2003 :-). It would interesting to test the performance in terms of formula calculation speed.

Comment: @ScottCraner, no I wasn't talking to you and yes I know that when you get into the 100k points you don't care about rating. Truthfully I don't care too much about points either, however I'm not sure I would give myself enough credit to say I like to help people out --I consider my obsession with SO as a variation of doing Suduko or cross-word puzzles. Kind of relaxing to tackle mini-challneges. It's either that or I play video games... (anyone here play Fortnite?!?).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is worth adding at this late stage, but you could consider using VAR like this:

```
=VAR(IF(A1:G1,A1:G1))=0
```

One slight benefit is that it should work for positive and negative numbers, although this isn't part of the question. It will error if all are zeroes, but this isn't supposed to happen.

[image]

Comment: I like the succinct nature! Easy to add an iferror to equal true if all zeros....

Comment: I also like this answer a lot. Using an array formula is something I thought I might see but I never thought it would be this elegant. Very nice solution.